# update rows with checkbox but conflicts with other buttons

Tags: php, html

I made a form so that I can update my database with values. The problem that I have is that it conflicts with other buttons. The other buttons are working with an AJAX request. But they aren't working when they are in the form. So I need another solution.

I tried to make the last button also an AJAX request but it won't get the post values.

**What I have know:**

```php
function getUsers($orgID, $type)
{
    require 'functions/conn.php';

    $sql = "SELECT users.*, parts.*, keuze.* FROM ((users INNER JOIN parts ON users.part_id = parts.part_id) INNER JOIN keuze ON users.keuze_ID = keuze.ID) WHERE users.org_id = '" . $orgID . "' AND users.active IN ($type);";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<tr id="' . $row['user_id'] . '" class="changeUser">';
            echo '  <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="' . $row['user_id'] . '"></td>';
            echo '  <td>' . $row['fnln'] . '</td>';
            echo '  <td>' . $row['username'] . '</td>';
            echo '  <td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
            echo '  <td>' . $row['keuze'] . '</td>';
            echo '  <td>';           
            if ($row['active'] == 0 && $row['eind_tijd'] != 0 || $row['active'] == 2 && $row['eind_tijd'] != 0) {
                echo '      <button class="button button-green" onclick="approveOne('.$row['user_id'].', '.$_SESSION['org_id'].')">Approve</button>';
            }
            echo '      <button class="button button-red" onclick="deleteFromRelation(' . $row['user_id'] . ');">Delete</button><br/>';
            echo '  </td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

```html
 <form action="functions/save/saveAllusers.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="form-group col-md-12"><select name="tijd" class="form-control col-md-12" id="Eindtijd"><?php getTime(); ?></select></div>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitChangeUser" class="button button-green" value="Change time"/>
     <?php getUsers($_SESSION['org_id'], 0); getUsers($_SESSION['org_id'], 2); ?>
</form>
```

**AJAX request (buttons in php)**

```
function approveOne(user, org) {
    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure to approve this users?',
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Approve user'
    }).then(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "functions/save/approveUser.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {user, org},
            success: function (data) {
                swal(
                    'Approved!',
                    'You have approved the selected user.',
                    'Success'
                );
                $("#newUsers").hide(250);
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
}

function deleteUser(userID) {
    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure you want to delete your user account?',
        text: "You can't revert this step.",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Delete'
    }).then(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "functions/delete/deleteUser.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {userID},
            success: function (data) {
                swal({
                    title: 'Deleted!',
                    text: 'You have deleted the user.',
                    type: 'success',
                }).then (function(){
                    //redirect de user
                    location.reload();
                });
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

What I expect is that i can update my rows just like I can right know and that the other buttons keep working. If I click the approve or delete button (the buttons in the php) it wants to do the same as the button in the html. And ofcourse it it gives an error that it can't insert. But the buttons aren't made for that... And when they are out the form it works good like normal.

Comment: can you explain more how they are not working or how they conflict, because from your code, they shouldn't

Comment: _"But they aren't working when they are in the form"_ - What happens? Nothing? Have you checked the console for potential errors? Where's the js code you have in the `onclick`-events? Please add _all_ relevant code to the question. If you have a button in a form that shouldn't submit the form, add `type="button"` on the buttons. The default is `type="submit"` which submits the form.

Comment: @RayA Well if I click the approve or delete button (the buttons in the php) it wants to do the same as the button in the html

Comment: Can you add `type="button"` on the two `<button>`-elements and see if that helps?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it works! But can you explain why it works right now?

Comment: I am explaining it in my first comment. The `<button>` element has the default `type="submit"`. So if a button is inside a form, it will submit the form (just like your `<input type="submit"... />`). When you add `type="button"`, the button will no longer submit the form.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ahh okay thank you!